# Windowless room Air Conditioning, Sky light only

Tags: air-conditioning

I have a dilemma. I have a windowless room in Brooklyn. Only a sky light 10 feet up. Right next to my room however is the washer/dryer. Not sure if that would help at all, but my landlord isn't open to a big hole going up out the roof. I don't know what to do anymore. Possibly a portable or ductless with a drain box? Can I connect it to the washer/dryer pipes? I have no idea please help, I don't care if its cute I just need to feel cool in this heat.

Answer (score 2):

The portable A/C units that I've seen have a 3 or 4" diameter air duct to get rid of the hot air. Usually you hang that out of a window.   If you are not looking for a permanent solution, you could connect it to the air vent hose that comes out of the back of your dryer.  You would have to switch it back to actually use the dryer.  I'm not positive but I'm guessing that the A/C unit has a condensation reservoir that you have to empty occasionally like a dehumidifier so you probably don't need to connect that to any hose or piping.

Comment: Many portable ACs blow their condensed water through their vent. I suspect water and dryer lint will not make a good combination

Comment: The air coming out of the back of the dryer is pretty moist too.  I'd personally give it a try if it's ridiculously hot.  You do have to be able to pull the dryer out of it's place to get to the air vent on the back.    The only other option would be to by and extension for the air hose out of the door of the room to an outside window if you can get to one.   Where ever you buy the unit should be able to help you get the right thing.

Comment: but the dryer is expecting to have to vent out a long pipe.  AC will be designed with enough force to vent out its vent, put possibly not its vent + dryer vent length.  It may work fine, but water building up in the vent is something to look out for.

Comment: Hot air can carry more moisture than cool air (hence: A/C condensate). Air at ambient temperatures (e.g. 90 degrees F) is already not saturated (or it would have condensed on something already). By definition, the A/C exhaust is hotter than ambient (say 120F) so has *more* water carrying capacity.  Even if it cools *to* ambient (90), it has the same water capacity as it started with.  Dryers, by contrast, take ambient and add a lot of foreign water.

Answer (score 2):

Tap into the dryer vent. Get a 4" vent wye, and put a damper on it to close when the AC is not in use.:

[image]
[image]